# Verification failed: 0x1A security violation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I made some changes in grub by mistake, and now I m getting Verification failed :0x1A security violation 
In My Hp pavilion notebook laptop is dual bootable and I m also not able to open any boot option during startup time.

Comment: Can you boot from any Ubuntu install media? (USB/DVD)

Comment: Nope ,Even boot option is not coming after pressing F12

Comment: For those who have stumbled on this question recently, Canonical updated their UEFI signing keys. More info here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1456906/1598467

Answer (score -2):

Your last resort would be removing the bios chip from the motherboard using a hot air solder, then flashing it with a usb programmer. Take the laptop to a repair shop and ask them to do that.

Comment: Thanks @theroguecode for the advice. This issue was resolved by the same way as u mentioned.

Comment: Theoretically this probably will/did work, but it's somewhat overkill.