# I tried portabilizing the installation of my Kubuntu 22.04, now I have a problem with grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, kubuntu

What have I done:

- I used a live kubuntu usb to install kubuntu on a usb drive using computer A.
- The kubuntu installation was on the USB drive, but the grub was tied to the ssd of computer A (coexisting with windows), so the installation was not portable, and only worked on that PC

a few months have passed

- I took the USB drive on which kubuntu was installed and from another computer B, I formatted it and followed this tutorial to install kubuntu in a truly portable way https://itsfoss.com/intsall-ubuntu-on-usb/
- Everything worked fine, kubuntu starts from a USB stick on computer B.
- On computer A, however, when I try to boot kubuntu from the usb drive, I get a "reset system" message and the system reboots.
- Trying to boot a kubuntu live USB on computer A I get the problem "Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation"
- Trying to boot from the "ubuntu" entry that I used to start the old installation (therefore the grub on the local SSD) I get the grub screen with the terminal.

What I would like to do:

- Remove the grub from computer A and use the one on the USB drive to portabilize the installation.

What I can't do:

- Format the SSD

What I wouldn't want to do if not literally indispensable:

- Disassemble computer A to extract the SSD and modify its contents on another computer.

I apologize for my English as I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Do  you have an ESP on external drive? Is grub now installed to it. You can directly boot it, if grub is installed, but boot entry will be like booting live installer. Or selecting a drive entry not an "ubuntu" entry. Does fstab's UUID of ESP match UUID of ESP on external drive? Does GUID/partUUID of ubuntu entry match GUID of ESP? compare: `cat /etc/fstab` & `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` & `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Comment: Upgrade the firmware on both PCs. Check that Secure Boot is disabled in both PCs.

Comment: Both computers have firmware updated to the latest version.
The external drive has the ESP flag active as described in the tutorial I linked.
If I select the drive entry with the installed kubuntu from computer B, I get the message "reset system".
I'm not familiar with the GUID/partUUID stuff, but I think that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems that there was more than one problem, and this obviously complicated the resolution.

First I removed the grub from the SSD of computer A following this procedure: https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1748690. However, the problem was not yet resolved.

After reading this page ([Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation from 22.04.1 live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456891/verification-failed-0x1a-security-violation-from-22-04-1-live-usb)) I checked the kubuntu versions more carefully. In the first installation of kubuntu on computer A I must have used Kubuntu 22.04.3. I think this changed the secure boot certifications on computer A. In the second installation made from computer B I used Kubuntu 22.04.1, which instead has different/obsolete secure boot certifications, which is why the USB drive did not load the operating system and the live distribution gave the error "Verification failed: 0x1A security violation".

I rebuilt a live distribution with Kubuntu 22.04.3 and reinstalled kubuntu on the usb drive using computer A and everything works now.​